# perl - get non-zero exit code if at least one of the listed files does not exist

Tags: bash, 22.04, perl

As for the cat command, which returns an exit code other than 0 if at least one file in the list does not exist, but continuing its execution, I would also like the same behavior for the "perl" command, which while continuing its execution, unfortunately it does not return a non-0 exit code when encountering one or more missing files.

This solution provided by another topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192300:

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ -f $ARGV[0] or die"no file" } s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt
```

Correctly returns a non-0 exit code when a file is not found but does not continue executing for other files. Indeed this:

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ -f $ARGV[0] or die"no file" } s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt existent-file.txt
```

doesn't give the output of the second file but only the error for the first non-existent file.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76209021/7552

Comment: You are evaluating only the first argument and killing your script immediately after if the file isn't existent ... This will neither evaluate all files nor continue if the first argument is a nonexistent file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Perl guru either, but you are evaluating only the first argument and killing your script immediately after the file isn't existent ... This will neither evaluate all files passed as arguments nor continue to process other files if the first argument is a nonexistent file.

Therefor, your script is not going to work as you expect when you pass multiple arguments(*filenames*) to it.

You need to first evaluate all the command-line arguments with e.g. `foreach my $arg (@ARGV) { ... }` then set the exit code accordingly and exit with that code at the end.

i.e. something like this:

```perl
perl -p -e 'my $exit_code; BEGIN{
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {-f $arg or $exit_code = 2} }
END{exit($exit_code)}
s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt existent-file.txt
```

---

**Notice**(*might save your time*): AFAIK `die` doesn’t have an exit status of its own nor does it "directly" alter the script's exit status … Therefor, the exit code number `2` you see is actually for `-f $ARGV[0]` and it means `no such file or directory` … Those code numbers are [limited in variety and are distinct](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/operating-system-error-codes/#linux-error-codes) … Therefore, it is perfectly fine to assign/set them manually in a controlled environment as such although if an argument passed might be a directory, then it might result in a different error number but that’s what "controlled" is about as you can change `-f` to `-e` for instance or double evaluate with a conditional or even add your own extended error evaluation/containment code to do exactly what you want.

Furthermore, `die` can have a *side effect(exception)* that will result in additional error codes e.g. `22`(*invalid argument*) thus contaminating your script and that might not be what you want if you aim to preserve some actual exit status ... See why [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die) ... You might however be able to contain/neutralize this side effect partially(*although might not be reliable ... Use `exit` instead*) with something like `eval{die "blabla" ... }` and in which case this might directly alter your script's exit status as well.

However, you might be able to both use `die` and **not** `exit` and preserve the actual exit status from `-f $ARGV...` at the same time while not killing your script immaturely if you properly move the evaluation to an `END` block with something like this:

```perl
perl -p -e 'my @arr; BEGIN{@arr = @ARGV}
END{ foreach my $arg (@arr) { -f $arg or die"no file"} }
s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt existent-file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN { -f $ARGV[0] or push @nofile, $ARGV[0]; } END { die "no file: ". join ", ", @nofile if @nofile; } s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt existent-file.txt
```

Comment: Why exit code is 22 and not 2 as in the question case?

Comment: can you explain this solution please?

Comment: First, this isn't "the perl command". You're writing a one-line perl *script* in the language Perl. What the BEGIN block does is execute code before the rest of script executes. The END block executes code after the rest of the script executes. If you're married to a particular exit code, you shouldn't be using `die`, which takes a string argument, you should be using `exit` which takes a numeric argument. What my addition to your script does is delay the exit of the script with a non-zero exit code until after it has processed the existing files.

Comment: Look at Raffa's answer below. It's got the "just give me something that works" that you want.